# "Two dead found dead"

Tags: redundancy

Is it proper English to say 'Two dead found dead' like we read in the breaking news below?

[image]

Comment: It is almost certainly a typo.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it in the context of *headlinese* grammar.  What it is intended to mean is another thing though.  Perhaps it's meant to convey that there are two people dead, and they were dead when they were found- as opposed to two people who died shortly after they were found- barely alive.

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical (for headlinese: proper English would be "The two dead were found dead") but terribly bad style (repetition like that sounds pleonastic (and is so here), and is not euphonious)

Comment: It is a headline/crawl, written by a harried producer in a hurry.  You've never written anything and then, on rereading, discovered that you'd duplicated a word or some such?

Comment: It's probably not a typo -- It can have the meaning of "Two people whom we knew to be dead were found already dead" as opposed to "Two people whom we knew to be dead were found alive and then murdered or died." However, it is in absolute poor taste to write this like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *improper* English, but it's very odd pragmatically, since the formula "[noun/substantive] found [adjective]" seems to presuppose that their [noun/substantive]-ness is existing information, and present their [adjective]-ness as new information. Such deviations from normal pragmatics are sometimes found in humor (e.g., ["obvious ___ is obvious"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22obvious+*+is+obvious%22)), but that does not seem to be the intent here.

Rather, I think this was almost certainly either a typo/thinko (perhaps they meant to write "two [noun/substantive] found dead" for some different [noun/substantive]) or an editing error (perhaps they started with "two dead", decided to expand it to "two found dead", and messed up).